# Is it possible to evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^{20}\frac{1}{r(r+1)}$ using $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac12n(n+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Evaluate $$\sum_{r=1}^{20}\frac{1}{r(r+1)}$$

It splits into $$\sum_{r=1}^{20}\frac{1}{r}-\sum_{r=1}^{20}\frac{1}{r+1}$$

I'm stuck on how to apply the standard result $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac12n(n+1)$ to it. It may be simpler to use the method of differences but is that the only straightforward way?

Comment: **Hint:** Notice that the sum is $$\sum_{r=1}^{20} \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{20}-\frac{1}{21}$$ $$=\frac{1}{1}+\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\cdots +\left(-\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{20}\right)-\frac{1}{21}.$$

**Note:** I am not putting this as an answer as I believe the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to apply your standard result - just write down the two sums you have term by term (do it for a sum from $1$ to $5$ by hand to get the pattern of it) and you will see how most of the terms cancel, and then it will be magically obvious what the answer is - and easy to prove.

This "telescoping series" phenomenon is incredibly useful when dealing with reciprocals, but also in other contexts - so this simple example is well worth understanding in detail.

Comment: is it not possible to apply the standard result here? I can see the method of differences is much easier in this case but the question was in a set of questions about using standard results and I'm not sure it was there just to catch out people.

Comment: @GezBishop "The standard result" you quote for summing $\frac 12 r(r+1)$ really doesn't help. What you have is a new standard technique for a different kind of sum.

Comment: Note this answer is directed at trying to help the original poster with the specific issue which seems to have caused a problem, and which is not dealt with in the answers to the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{r=1}^{20}\frac{1}{r}-\sum_{r=1}^{20}\frac{1}{r+1}= \sum_{r=1}^{20}\frac{1}{r}-\sum_{r=2}^{21}\frac{1}{r}= \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{21}=\frac{20}{21}$